# Is the extension integral?

Tags: commutative-algebra

We have an injective homomorphism $f $ from an affine algebra $A$ (over $k $) to a polynomial ring $k [x,y,z] $, where $k $ is a field.

Is this extension integral, ie. can we say that this $f $ induces a surjection on the spectra?

Comment: Not necessarily, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389036/dominant-morphism-between-affine-varieties-induces-injection-on-coordinate-rings

Comment: What about $A=k[x]$? Are $y,z$ integral over $A$?