Assume $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an integral and dominant morphism of schemes, then $\operatorname{dim}X=\operatorname{dim}Y$.
I found the following lemma and its proof:

Definition A scheme morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is called integral if it is affine and for any affine open $spec(A)=U\subset Y$ and its preimage $spec(B)=f^{-1}(U)\subset X$, the assocaited ring map $A\rightarrow B$ is a integral ring extension. It does not require that $A,B$ have to be integral domains.
Lemma Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an integral and dominant morphism of schemes, then $\operatorname{dim}X=\operatorname{dim}Y$.
Proof: We first claim $$\operatorname{dim}X\leq \operatorname{dim} Y.$$ We know for any scheme $X$ and any open cover of $X=\cup_i U_i$, $\operatorname{dim}X=\sup(\operatorname{dim}U_i)$. Let $Y=\cup_i U_i$ be an affine open covering of $Y$, then $X=\cup_i f^{-1}(U_i)$ is an open affine covering of $X$, because $f$ is integral, in particular it is affine, i.e. the preimage of affine is affine. Hence, in order to show $\operatorname{dim} X\leq \operatorname{dim}Y$, it is sufficient to show $$\operatorname{dim}(f^{-1}(U_i))\leq \operatorname{dim}(U_i),\forall i.$$
Therefore, without loss of generality one can assume both $X,Y$ are affine. Let $X=\operatorname{spec}B, Y= \operatorname{spec} A$ and $\varphi:A\rightarrow B$ be the associated ring map. Note that $$\bar{\varphi}:A/\ker(\varphi)\rightarrow B$$ is integral ring extension. Then by using going up and incomparability one can conclude $$\operatorname{dim}(A)\geq \operatorname{dim}(A/\ker)=\operatorname{dim}(B).$$
Then we claim $\operatorname{dim}(A/\ker)=\operatorname{dim}(B)$ as $f$ is dominant hence $\ker(\varphi)=0$.

I understand everything until the second claim (exactly the last row). Why does the fact that $f$ is dominant imply that $\ker(\varphi)=0$? I think it is true if $A,B$ are both integral domains but for general rings $A,B$ I am skeptical if it is true. What I think is for example if $A$ is a ring whose nilradical is a prime ideal then the scheme map induced by $A\rightarrow A/\sqrt{0}$ is also dominant.
This proof appears on the very first page of lecture notes written by a professor in my university. Here is the link.

The definition I learnt is that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is integral if it is affine and for each affine open $U=spec(A)\subset Y$ and its preimage $f^{-1}(U)=spec(B)\subset X$, the associated ring map $A\rightarrow B$ is a integral ring extension. It does not require $A,B$ have to be integral domains.

The definition of dominant morphism between affine varietes is equivalent to asking your $\varphi$ to be injective. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389036/dominant-morphism-between-affine-varieties-induces-injection-on-coordinate-rings

Your first comment is good context and should be in your post. You also don't say where you found this lemma - could you also add that to your post with an [edit]?

Thanks. I already added  it to the text :)

I guess you want to say $Y=\cup U_i$ and $X=\cup f^{-1}(U_i)$ in the proof

Thanks I already corrected my typos

In fact $\mathrm{ker}(\varphi)$ may not be $0$, such as in your example $A\rightarrow A/\sqrt{0}$. But because $f$ is dominant, we have $\mathrm{ker}(\varphi)\subset\sqrt{0}$ :
Let $p$ is a minimum prime ideal of $A$, because $f$ is dominant ,there exists $q\in \mathrm{spec}(B)$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(q)=p$. Than $\mathrm{ker}(\varphi )=\varphi^{-1}(0)\subset  \varphi^{-1}(\cap q_i)=\cap \varphi^{-1}(q_i)=\cap p_i=\sqrt{0}$. Here $p_i$ ranges over all minimum prime ideal of $A$, and $q_i\in \mathrm{spec}(B)$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(q_i)=p_i$.
Then $\mathrm{dim} (A)=\mathrm{dim}(A/\mathrm{ker})=\mathrm{dim}(A/\sqrt{0})$.
